# Материалы за 24 часа

Tags: php, sql

```
$timeLimit = time() - (1440 * 60);
$tasks_add = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `notifications` WHERE `type` = 6 AND `ntime` > $timeLimit"));
```

Правильно ли я вывожу материалы за 24 часа?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Лучше так:

```
SELECT count(id) FROM notifications WHERE type = 6 AND ntime > (now() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

Comment: @mantigatos, тоже интересно :) Но хотелось бы и узнать ответ на мой вопрос.

Comment: Ответ  - неправильно.

Представьте себе, что происходит в вашем коде:

1. Вы вычисляете таймстамп для времени 24 часа назад.
2. Вы забираете ВСЕ данные которые были за эти 24 часа, по всем полям, со всем содержимым. При том что вам **не надо все эти данные**.
3. Вы передаёте эти данные в PHP.
4. PHP считает количество строк в возвращённых данных.


В приведённом варианте сервер БД сам посчитает количество строк, к тому-же сделает это быстрее.

Comment: @mantigatos, Ваш код вообще выдал 0 материалов, хотя их более 700 на самом деле за 24 часа :D

Comment: В ответе рабочий код, проверьте хорошенько. И раз уж 700 записей, то лучше конечно использовать его.

Comment: @mantigatos, Вопрос в догонку - `now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY` - выполняет то же самое или нет? Т.е. за последние 24 часа? Или за весь прошлый день и часть этого?

@ModaL, `SELECT count(id)` использовали? А `id` у вас есть?

Лично я предпочитаю `SELECT count(1)`

UPD: надеюсь не `mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SQL_в_ответе"))` использовали) И лучше так 'count(id) AS count_id'

Comment: @Ворон, вот по-поводу mysql_num_rows. У меня например есть запрос: $query1 = SELECT * FROM `users` LIMIT 5, чтобы посчитать мне все материалы, а юзаю $query2 = mysql_num_rows(SELECT * FROM `users`);. Это вообще правильно? 100% есть что-то проще...

Comment: А какого типа ntime?

Comment: @mantigatos, выдаёт Resource id #5: $tasks_add = mysql_query("SELECT count(id) FROM notifications WHERE type = 6 AND `ntime` > (now() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)");

Comment: @ModaL, смотря что Вам требуется. Если получить ответ, обработать его и между делом получить количество - то почему бы нет - можно и Ваш вариант использовать (есс-но вынеся mysql_query в переменную)

Но если запрос выполняется только ради количества - то лучше по-другому. Вам написали уже как.

Т.е. для получения только количества достаточно:

    $row = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(1) AS `user_cnt` FROM `users`");
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($row); //$result['user_cnt'] - кол-во

UPD: и лучше на mysqli переключиться, mysql - deprecated